# The Hahn-Hellinger Theorem

Tags: operator-algebras, von-neumann-algebras

People can tell the question is not up to the mark, but I felt without understanding the Hahn-Hellinger Theorem properly there is no point talking von Neumann algebras for myself. So can any body help me out clearing the concept of Hahn-Hellinger Theorem, what is the game playing inside the theorem, I tried many books and I am not able to get with clarity. More specifically how cyclic vectors are connected with multiplicity of self-adjoint operator, this theorem say any self-adjoint operator in $\mathcal{H}$ is equivalent to a multiplication operator $M_{z}$ on $\oplus L^2(X,\mu_{i})$, how it looks the case at least for finite dimensional case, how direct sum take cares multiplicity of the eigenvalue that I did not get, Also it is not clear all the measure joined to single measure. Further why cyclic decomposition remembers the spectral multiplicity. Please help. Thanks in advance

Comment: "without understanding the Hahn-Hellinger Theorem properly there is no point talking von Neumann algebras": a dubious claim, at best.  Arguably, it is much easier to approach the spectral theorem via von Neumann algebras, not vice versa.  A normal operator N on a Hilbert space H generates a commutative von Neumann algebra A, whose Gelfand spectrum S is a measurable space.  Furthermore, H is an A-module, and the category of A-modules is equivalent to the category of Hilbert bundles over S, yielding a Hilbert bundle B over S.  The dimensions of fibers of B are precisely spectral multiplicities.

Comment: @Dmitri Pavlov can you please ellaborate how you connecting modules and hilbert bundles. dimension of fibers to spectral theorem, I will be helpful if you give the litle more clarification

Comment: A few more details can be found in my notes https://dmitripavlov.org/notes/2018s-6325.pdf, see, in particular, 9.11, 9.14, 9.20.  Many things in the text are hyperlinked and will lead you to the relevant definitions.

Comment: Thanks for the link.